# SELECT 1 - idle in transaction

Tags: postgresql

Across my problems with the load on the database, I just have found a new, odd one. I understand, that some queries might be in `IDLE IN TRANSACTION` status, when I did something wrong in my application layer. However, just now I have spotted this query having this status for almost 20 seconds now:

```
SELECT 1;
```

This is the internal mechanism of JBoss AS, checking if the connection is still valid. I cannot understand how it be idle in transaction. Any hints welcome.

Comment: A transaction was started beforehand (maybe automatically, as it's done by default by some clients) and never committed.  The query you see is the last executed one, it can be basically anything in an idle transaction.

Comment: I still do not understand how pure SELECT 1 can start a transaction.

Comment: Like dezso said: `SELECT 1` just happens to be the last query executed in a transaction that was started with a manual `BEGIN` (not in `autocommit` mode), either by you or by your client. The transaction is idle, *not* the query. It was neither committed nor rolled back and waits for more commands.

Answer (score 7):

`idle in transaction` means pretty much what it suggests: there is an open transaction doing nothing at the moment.

What you see can be easily reproduced.  Do the following in one session (disable autocommit in your client if necessary - usually it isn't, an explicit `BEGIN;` will do that automatically):

```
test=>
    BEGIN;

    SELECT 1;
```

In an other session, let's see how it looks in `pg_stat_activity`:

```
test=> SELECT pid, 
              datname, 
              usename, 
              xact_start, 
              query_start, 
              state, 
              state_change, 
              query,
              now() 
       FROM pg_stat_activity;

pid          │ 13639
datname      │ test
usename      │ dezso
xact_start   │ 2015-10-23 10:14:36.853529+02
query_start  │ 2015-10-23 10:15:15.838252+02
state        │ idle in transaction
state_change │ 2015-10-23 10:15:15.838365+02
query        │ SELECT 1
now          │ 2015-10-23 10:16:24.340721+02
```

Here we see four different timestamps:

- the time when the transaction started (`xact_start`),
- the time when the query started (`query_start`),
- the time when the transaction state last changed (`state_change`, I suppose it's the end of the query) and
- the current timestamp (when the above query was run).

Between the last two the transaction is idling, but the last query is still shown.

**To answer your question:** many clients have autocommit disabled by default.  In this case, a transaction is started silently when the first command (`SELECT 1;`, for example) is issued - and then never closed.  In this case you'll see what you experience currently and I reproduced above.

AFAIK there is a way to persuade JBoss AS to turn it off.  This might help: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionaldataaccessandtheauto-commitmode

Comment: Sometimes, my applications get this problem 'open but never closed', there are many reasons on clients making that problem. I'm using a script to monitor `idle in transaction` state from clients, then manually `terminate` those clients process.

Answer (score 0):

actually the reason for this was memory leak in application. Garbage collector did 'stop the world' collection, which freezes all threads of JBoss, that is why. But thanks for your help anyway, good to read about idle in transaction.